# css doesn't work in my partial imported into index.ejs

Tags: css, ejs, partials

I'm working with node and ejs, in my index.ejs file I have a partial called "sidebar.ejs"
but strangely the css that is in index.css does not apply to the partial imported into index.ejs

Can someone help me

Thanks!

index.ejs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x10I1.png)

sidebar:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcxdg.png)

css (index.css):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICCz8.png)

I tried different ways to fix it, but none of them worked, I don't know why!